# Segmentation fault when trying to print string with a for loop in C

Tags: c, json, json-c

I am parsing a Wiktionary JSON dump with C in order to convert it into delimited format. My program works but when I print out my definition normally with the json_object_get_string function, I get brackets and quotation marks that I don't want to be shown. So I tried printing the string character by character, using a for loop and starting at the 4th character and stopping 3 before the termination character. But when I try doing this I keep getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp;

    struct json_object *sensestr;
    int glosseslength = 0;
    char *line;
    char *line_ii;
    char *prevword = NULL;
    int d = 0;
    int n_examples = 0;
    struct json_object *parsed_json;
    struct json_object *parsed_senses;
    struct json_object *pos;
    struct json_object *word;
    struct json_object *age;
    struct json_object *senses;
    struct json_object *sense;
    struct json_object *examples;
    struct json_object *example;

    struct json_object *glosses;
    struct json_object *tags;
    struct json_object *forg_text;
    struct json_object *eng_text;

    int list = 0;
    int wordlen;
    bool has_period = false;
    bool put_newline;

    int ma = 0;
    int mb = 0;

    char *alt;

    size_t n_friends;
    size_t len;
    size_t len_ii;

    size_t read_ii;
    size_t read;
    size_t n_glosses;
    size_t i;

    fp = fopen("kaik.json","r");

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        //printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        //printf("%s", line);
        parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(line);
        json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "senses", &senses);
        json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "word", &word);
        json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "pos", &pos);

        wordlen = strlen(json_object_get_string(word));

        if (prevword == NULL || strcmp(prevword, json_object_get_string(word)) != 0) {
            if (list != 0) {
                printf("\n");
            }

            printf("%i. %s\t", list, json_object_get_string(word));
        }

        list = list + 1;

        free(prevword);

        prevword = strdup(json_object_get_string(word));

        printf("[%s] ", json_object_get_string(pos));

        if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "senses", &senses)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < json_object_array_length(senses); x++) {
                sense = json_object_array_get_idx(senses, x);

                json_object_object_get_ex(sense, "glosses", &glosses);

                if (json_object_get_string(glosses)) {
                    glosseslength = strlen(json_object_get_string(glosses));

                    for (int e = 3; e < glosseslength - 3; e++) {
                        printf("%c", json_object_get_string(glosses)[e]);        //this for loop causes a segmentation fault for some reason
                    }

                    printf("%s", json_object_get_string(glosses));   //this works
                }

                printf(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Right off the top, both `line` and `len` are uninitialised... What do you expect `getline()` to do when passed garbage values?

Comment: Is that why printing object "glosses" as a string works but printing character by character doesn't?

Comment: `printf` with the `%s` format specifier expects a null terminated string. Is that what you're passing it? It's unclear from your code, because we don't know what you're actually reading into `glosses`. To print a single character, use the `%c` format.

Comment: Explain how you use the index e to get a single char and print it.

Comment: Yes, the string is null terminated. `printf("%s", json_object_get_string(glosses));` Works just fine but the for loop that prints the string character by character above that doesn't. I can't work out why. I am passing in a Wiktionary dump https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Vietnamese/index.html, specifically the all word sense list.

Comment: crap i was messing with it before i posted it and didn't realize i forgot to put the [e] back on the string and change the it back to %c

Comment: The edit was what I had initially before I was messing with it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: got it will do rn

Comment: So I tried reproducing the issue by putting one of the strings that 'json_object_get_string(glosses)' is = to which is "[ \"An Lão (a rural district of Haiphong, Vietnam).\" ]". And trying to print the string in the same way and it printed perfectly fine. I am already checking for the existence of json_object_get_string(glosses) before printing so i don't know why I am having issues with the code above. I'm gonna try reproducing it again.

Comment: I found the the issue. For whatever reason I had this laying around in the code `wordlen = strlen(json_object_get_string(word));` unnoticed and it only caused problems when I printed an unrelated string character by character with a for loop. It somehow didn't cause any issues when i printed it as a string with %s.

Comment: That difference does not make sense. You put the string into `strlen`. That function accesses all the memory until it finds a 0 byte. If that does not cause a segfault, it is highly unlikely that your loop accessing the same string could cause any trouble. You only access memory that was successfully accessed by `strlen` before. The same applies to printing with `%s` . Same memory, no reason for a difference. In fact, the loop even touches less bytes of the string than the `printf` after the loop.

Comment: I also don't see how `wordlen = strlen(json_object_get_string(word));` would be able to affect the `for` loop far below.

Comment: I don't understand it either but for some reason it works when I delete that line.